# Wrong height in iPhone simulator when webview resize using jQuery Mobile and Cordova

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile

I tried to add AdMob into Cordova project, so I modified the webview size when app loading.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.

    /*add admob*/
    CGSize sizeOfScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGSize sizeOfView = self.view.bounds.size;
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];

    if  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        //landscape view code
        CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0, sizeOfScreen.width - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape).height-statusBarFrame.size.width);
        bannerView_ = [[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape origin:origin] autorelease];
    }else{
        //portrait view code
        CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0, sizeOfScreen.height - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height-statusBarFrame.size.height);
        bannerView_ = [[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait origin:origin] autorelease];
    }

    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    request.testing = YES;
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:request];

    /*resize webview*/
    CGRect webViewFrame = [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] applicationFrame ];
    CGRect windowFrame = [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ];

    webViewFrame.origin = windowFrame.origin;

    if  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        webViewFrame.size.height = sizeOfScreen.width-CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape).height-statusBarFrame.size.width;
        webViewFrame.size.width = sizeOfScreen.height;

    }else{
        webViewFrame.size.height = windowFrame.size.height-CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height-statusBarFrame.size.height;
        webViewFrame.size.width = sizeOfScreen.width;
    }

    self.webView.frame = webViewFrame;

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Now the size of the webview should be 320X410.
But, more about 10px blank block at the bottom of the page when it loads.
The the same issues also appears in the landscape view.

This is executed screenshots.
[image: This is executed screenshots]

This issues only when webview resized, and content exceeds the screen has no issues.
This issues will appear in the iphone 5.0 5.1 6.0 simulator and not in Retina 4-inch portrait view and not in ipad simulator.

This is html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Single page template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert($(window).height());
    alert($(document).height());
    alert($("body").height());
  });
</script> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Single page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>This is a single page boilerplate template that you can copy to build your first jQuery Mobile page. Each link or form from here will pull a new page in via Ajax to support the animated page transitions.</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

config.xml

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
```

app inits

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = NO;
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

Cordova 2.3.0
Xcode 4.5.2
jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 beta1, 1.2.0

How should I fix this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem made ​​the reason is jquery-mobile limits the minimum height of the screen.
In portrait screen `min-height` is 420px, In landscape screen `min-height` is 300px.
When webview height is modified to 410px, more about 10px blank block at the bottom.

jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css

```
media screen and (orientation: portrait){
  .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page {
    min-height: 420px;
  }
}
media screen and (orientation: landscape){
  .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page {
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}
```

Overwrite or remove css rules can fix this issues.

```
<html style="min-height:0px">
```

Or

```
html{
  min-height: 0px !important; 
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but for those who think you can just put it in the `<body>` and be fine, you're wrong! It doesn't work there, but it does when you put it on `<html>`!

Answer (score 1):

use the viewport tag in the html head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

also make sure `EnableViewportScale` mast be `true` to enable scale.

Comment: I've tried, viewport tag can not solve this issue. Use 
parameter `height=device-height` height becomes 480, but webview height of only 410. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The bottom of the blank region changing large. [screenshots](http://img.sunbon.net/ios2.png)

Comment: change the initial-scale value then?

Comment: strange, I tried to to modify the `initial-scale`, but still looks original scale, I edited the questions put related settings up, maybe my settings are wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: change inital and max scale

Comment: I found `EnableViewportScale` mast be `true` to enable scale. And modify `initial-scale` blank area enlarge, too.

Comment: I found the same issues are also in chrome and ie9, when width<360 or height<300. This issues is only the jquery mobile issues.

Comment: I think `.ui-mobile` in css is root of the problem. I think I know how to fix the problem.

Comment: I'am really appreciate your help, your answer is really useful, but isn't correct answer for question. I want to remove the bottom of the blank, But setting `initial-scale` make blank scale with. The issues should jquery-mobile set `min-height` in .css caused.